# How to make nested Library in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, audio, file-management, libraries

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to have nested libraries in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/113037/is-it-possible-to-have-nested-libraries-in-windows-7)

I want to make new "Songs" library inside "Music" Library.

How to do that?

How to make nested library in windows 7?

**Edit:** I know how to add folders to music library but i want to make new library inside music library.  Is that possible?

Comment: We could probably answer you better if you tell us what root folders you are including in your library, and you want the resulting library to appear.

Comment: propose closing this as a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/113037/is-it-possible-to-have-nested-libraries-in-windows-7

Comment: Why closing ??

My question older than this question ! :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot nest libraries; it doesn't make sense to do so.

Your Music library is an amalgamation of all music on your PC. Or, more generally, a library is 1 or more folders merged together.

So, you could have the contents of;

- C:\Music\Songs\
- D:\Downloads\Music\Songs\
- C:\Users\Wahid\Music\Songs\

...all appear in one folder ("library")

- Music\

If you want a "Songs" sub folder in the library, you should change the directory structure of the folders in your music library. Ie, instead of the above 3 directories, include:

- C:\Music\
- D:\Downloads\Music\
- C:\Users\Wahid\Music\

Now your Music library has a sub directory  "Songs".

- Music\Songs\

Comment: Using links inside a folder might allow something close to the request without file system re-organisation.