# Is it possible to have nested libraries in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, file-management, libraries

My goal is this: I have a library, say it's called Series. I store my series in two different places, one for watched episodes and one for unwatched episodes.

Obviously I can simply add the root folder of each location to a series library. What I would prefer to do is have a sub-library within Series for each series, for example:

> Series \ Lost
>
> Lost (Unwatched series)
>   Episode 3
>   Episode 4
>
> Lost (Watched series)
>   Episode 1
>   Episode 2

Is there a way to achieve this, or something approximating this (without having a full library for each series)?

P.S. I've read the other topic, but I was wondering if there was a possible workaround for this specific need. More out of hope than anything else. ;)

Comment: Sure this is a duplicate. Found it - http://superuser.com/questions/91560/how-to-make-nested-library-in-windows-7

Comment: @ChrisF et al: agree it's a dupe, but that dupe is a horrible question; i'd suggest closing that one and keeping this one.

Comment: Yup, I realise I duplicated the other question, but I was hoping that there was something overlooked in that one, since the question was rather unspecific. In any case, I suppose I will just have to use the adding each folder workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I have achieved is by adding the serie's directories one by one and grouping them by folders.

[image]

Additional tips: to group them in one disk/directory (without library) you could use junctions (command prompt `mklink /j ...`)

Comment: That looks like the best solution to me - thanks! Obviously sub-libraries would have been optimal, but this'll do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Nested libraries are certainly possible. (Tested with Windows 7 Ultimate x64 Service Pack 1)

Libraries (".library-ms" files as seen from the command prompt) are normally stored in "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries\" but you can move or copy them anywhere without any loss of functionality. The only place you can't copy them from is the virtual "Libraries\" location.

If you place library [B] in a location or subfolder of library [A], you can access [B] from within [A].

You cannot however set library [B] as one of the locations for library [A].  If you try, [B]'s locations will be added instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just append the watched folders names with `_Watched`. So you would have:

```
Seinfield (N:) (3)
S4
S5
S6
Seinfield_Watched (N:) (3)
S1
S2
S3
```