# Adding Virtual Library and/or Virtual Folder to latest Photo Gallery on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, dropbox, libraries, windows-photo-gallery

[How to make nested Library in windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/91560/how-to-make-nested-library-in-windows-7) and [Is it possible to have nested libraries in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/113037/is-it-possible-to-have-nested-libraries-in-windows-7) were both wanting to have Nested Libraries.

Clearly this is not possible, but it is possible to add one or more Virtual Library to the Windows 7 Libraries.  I can optimize the library for photos, but I cannot find any way to add my extra library so it sits below 'All photos and videos' so it does not need to be a nested library.

In addition does anyone know whether it is possible to add a Virtual Folder' to one of the Virtual Libraries so that it always contains a subset of the photos with a particular combination of tags. This would help me to publish a subset of the master photos that I hold on SkyDrive to Dropbox without having more than one copy on my local PC.

I am using WLXPhotoGallery.exe 14.4.3505.0912 (12-Oct-2012)